# ajax call only getting latest data on page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am having an issue where a json jquery call works only on refreshing the page after page load. ie on page load the data is not refreshed, on refreshing the page the data is refreshed. It feeds a select list. I have the following jquery ajax setup:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.ajaxSetup({'async': false, 'cache':false});
```

The following is my json statement:

```
    $.getJSON('ajax.cfm?action=refresh_bsu&site='+site+'&BaseLineYear='+BaselineYear+'&item=EnergyData', function(EnergyData) {
        SiteEnergyData = EnergyData; //Make it a global variable        
    });
```

This is the complete function:

```
function GetEnergyData(){
    var site = $("#busUnitSubGroup").val();
    var BaselineYear = $("#BaselineYear").val();

    SiteEnergyData = "";

    $.getJSON('ajax.cfm?action=refresh_bsu&site='+site+'&BaseLineYear='+BaselineYear+'&item=EnergyData', function(EnergyData) {
        SiteEnergyData = EnergyData; //Make it a global variable        
    }); 
}
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue please?

Thanks
JC

Comment: Where is getJSON called from?

Comment: It gets called in the doc ready function

Answer (score 0):

(a) Is `SiteEnergyData` defined outside the `GetEnergyData()` function (since you've noted it's a global variable).  If not, it'll only be visible within that function.

(b) Are you calling `GetEnergyData()` somewhere within the doc ready?  I'm assuming so since (for some reason) it works on reload but not initial load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var SiteEnergyData = "";  // (a) global variable... well, within doc ready
    GetEnergyData();          // (b) calls function once page is loaded

    ...

    function GetEnergyData(){
        ....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might need define the function outside of doc ready, so that it is defined by the time the doc.ready event fires:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    GetEnergyData();          

    ...

});

function GetEnergyData(){
  ....
}
```

However, it seems like you should be getting some javascript errors if that is the problem.  You should check the F12->console to see if there are any errors and what line it is saying the error is on.